# Recursive variation of Bubble Sort

Tags: java, sorting, recursion, data-structures, bubble-sort

I'm a student and I'm taking a DSA course. On our latest assignment we were asked to implement a recursive variation of bubble sort. The assignment was alrady submitted but I couldn't make it work and it's frustrating me. I've triple checked everything and I can't find the problem.

The general pseudo-code for the algorithm is:

```
if (n > 10) // n being the size of array A
   sort recursivley the first 2/3 elements in A (from 0 to ceil(2n/3))
   sort recursivley the last 2/3 elements in A (from floor(n/3) to n)
   sort recursivley the first 2/3 elements in A (from 0 to ceil(2n/3))
else
   use bubbleSort
```

This is the code I wrote:

```
public static void weirdSort(double[] arr, int start, int end, int size) {
        
        if (size > 10) {
            int weirdStart = (size / 3) - 1;
            int weirdEnd = (end - weirdStart) - 1;
            int weirdSize = (weirdEnd - start + 1);
            weirdSort(arr, start, weirdEnd, weirdSize);
            weirdSort(arr, weirdStart, end, weirdSize);
            weirdSort(arr, start, weirdEnd, weirdSize);
        }
        else 
            bubbleSort(arr, start, end);
    } // end of method

private static void bubbleSort(double arr[], int start, int end) {
        
        int size = end - start + 1;
        boolean noSwaps;
        
        for (int i = start; i < size; i++) {
            noSwaps = true;
            for (int j = start + 1; j < size - i; j++) {
                if (arr[j - 1] > arr[j]) {
                    swap(arr, j, j - 1);
                    noSwaps = false;
                } // end of condition
            } // end of (j) for loop
            if (noSwaps) // If no two elements were swapped by inner loop, array is sorted
                break;
        } // end of (i) for loop
    } // end of method
```

The problem is that it only sorts the array up to 2/3 of the first elements, the last 1/3 are unsorted (bubbleSort by itself works fine). I would really like to solve this on my own but I'm stuck, so I would apreciate any thoughts or suggestions on the matter but not a full solution.

Comment: So let's say the size of the array is 10, in that case 2/3 * 10 = 6 (rounding) , so we just sort the first 6 elements ?

Comment: @zenwraight No. when the array is of size 10 (or less) it simply sorts it with a simple bubble sort. In case the array is of size 11 (or greater) it recursively "breaks" it up to 2 parts. So for the sake of simplicity let's say it's 11. In that case elements the two parts are elements 0-6 and 4-11.  Then it sorts 0-6 using bubble sort, then 5-11 and then it goes back again to 0-6

Answer (score 0):

After calling `weirdSort` for all the 3 parts, those parts will be sorted but it has to be arranged so that the whole array is sorted, just like in a mergesort. So after calling the `weirdSort`, you have to run a loop and convert those 3 independent sorted arrays into a single sorted array.

Comment: I thought about that but my professor told me this can be done with no additional usage of memory, and with mergeSort you have to use O(n) memory. Also From the way my tests are coming out I have a feeling the problem is with the placement of the indices OR the way I'm calculating the 2/3 - 1/3 split of the array is messed up along the way of the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Your interpolation is wrong. Take an example,

```
weirdSort([...], 0, 11, 12):
  weirdStart = 12 / 3 - 1 = 3
  weirdEnd = 11 - 3 - 1 = 8
  weirdSize = 8 - 0 + 1 = 9
  // so far so good, but look at the second recursive call
weirdSort([...], 3, 11, 9):
  weirdStart = 9 / 3 - 1 = 2 // Wrong!
  // Other vars are now also wrong
```

You need to account for `start` when determining `weirdStart` and `weirdEnd`.

To get you started, you want something like,

```
third = (end - start + 1) / 3;
weirdStart = start + third;
weirdEnd = end - third;
```

In fact, don't pass `size` around at all, just compute it as `end - start + 1`.

You might want to adjust weirdStart/End by +/-1 depending on your specific needs.